# PCRE regex contraint for repetition

Tags: regex, sas, pcre

Could anyone please tell me how to write PCRE regex which contains 9 numbers and string can contain maximum 5 duplicates of single number. I can not find constraint for replication.

I use perl regular expression in sas

```
data regexp;
    if _n_=1 then pattern=prxparse("~^(48|0|48|0048|)+[1-9]{1}+[0-9]{8}~o");
    retain pattern;
    set new;
    if prxmatch(pattern,nr_tel) then flg=1; else flg=0;
run;
```

Thank you. 
What`s more :
I am trying to obtain 9 digits with prefix 48 or without prefix. (48|0|48|0048|) this part does not work for no prefix.

Comment: Please add pass/fail examples

Comment: That isn't Perl code. Please [edit] your question to tag it with the correct language.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what the pattern should match, but a regex pattern match is probably not the best way to solve this.

Comment: How about this: `^(?!.*?(\d)(.*?\1){5})\d{9}` which matches `"111112222"` but rejects `"111111222"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to anchor both ends with `^` and `$` so the length has meaning.
2. The lookahead `(?!.*?(\d)(.*?\1){5,})` asserts no more than 5 of the same numerals.
3. The match `\d{9}` matches 9 digits.

So:

```
/^(?!.*?(\d)(.*?\1){5,})\d{9}$/
```

does it.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0vV1KG/2/)

As noted in comments -- Thanks to Bart Kiers for perfecting the negative lookahead and it can be `(?!.*?(\d)(.*?\1){5})` but that is only marginally faster.

---

If you want an optional prefix, you would do:

```
/^(?!.*?(\d)(.*?\1){5,})(?:048|48)?\d{9}$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0vV1KG/3/)

Comment: `{5,}` can just be `{5}`, besides that, spot on! :)

Comment: @BartKiers: Thanks to you btw. I was struggling with the lookahead until you added the `?`

Comment: thank you, I found it useful. btw. Do you know how to put 48| or 048 or nothing on the begining (^48|048|) does not work for nothing.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are looking for with `(^48|048|)` at the beginning. Is that in addition to or instead of the pattern described?

Comment: yes, on the beginning have to be 48 or 0048  or 048 or nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question with examples. Is `048123456789` a match? That is 9 digits + `048`?

Comment: Ok, that`s 9 digits + 048 or noprefix

Comment: Insert `(?:048|48)?` prior to `\d{9}`